# function in a if statement with "and" not called

Tags: python, if-statement

Consider the following sample code:

```
def f1():
    return False

def f2():
    print("f2 called")

if f1() and f2():
    pass
```

On python 3.6, `f2` is not called. Is this for optimization reasons? Is it a bad practice to call functions in a if statement with `and`?

Comment: You can find the information you are looking for in the documentation: [Boolean Operations — `and`, `or`, `not`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes to both of your questions

f1() and f2() will RUN the whole function to see what value they return. f1() will return false. when you run your code, it will see that the first condition has returned false, so there is no need of checking the other conditions because the overall if condition has obviously been not satisfied. That's the optimization.

Yes it may be bad practice to call functions in if conditions, because it reduces readability and maintainability. It is better to set result of function calls equal to some variables and then check those variables. when you're debugging your code, it will be much easier to just check values returned by function calls then.

Refactoring your code would make it look like this:

```
f1_value = f1()
f2_value = f2()
if f1_value and f2_value:
        pass
```

**P.S.**
You might want to return some value in f2(). If you don't specify a return value, it will return None, which loosely translates to False in if conditions. I am not sure if you want that behavior, but if that's what you need, it would be much better to explicitly write out what you're returning

Comment: Maybe you want to call second only if first one succeeds.

Comment: that makes sense. In that case, you wouldn't want side effects of f2() to change some shared variable or do something else.
thanks @unalignedmemoryaccess

however I still believe function calls in if conditions look a bit messy. you can implement the conditional calling of f2 outside the if condition too. Might just be my personal opinion though, don't know what the rest of coding community has to say.

Comment: "Yes it may be bad practice to call functions in if conditions, because it reduces readability" no it isn't a bad practice

Answer (score 1):

`and` is only a logical operator in python.

```
if condition1 and condition2:
    #code
```

if condition1 is False then condition2 will not be checked, Only in case of condition1 is True then condition2 will be checked.